# Joomla Alias Redirects to the Wrong Page

Tags: joomla

I have a weird issue where when I create a new article in Joomla, no matter what it's called and visit it, it shows content from a completely different page (consistently the same page). In the content that shows, if I click on the title which is hyperlinked to it's own page, it goes to a different URL with the same content.

The aliases aren't the same on any of the pages and the content that shows is from a completely different article. I don't see any redirects on the site and there are a bunch of other articles that have been on the site for a while now that work fine.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Any chance you have a cache mechanism enable *plus* a SEF tool?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this problem:

- sh404SEF gone mad (Here's an example of the myriad of problems we had with this extensions: http://www.itoctopus.com/sh404-the-worst-joomla-extension ) if you have it installed.
- Weird redirects in the .htaccess file (have you checked it thoroughly?)
- Issues with your template
- An unstable SEF plugin installed on your website (other than sh404SEF )